# jquery telling me something is added to a table but it is not

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that is supposed to add data to a table when you click the button and a pop up comes up telling you it was added or there was a problem. A user can put data into the text areas and click on rate the box comes up and tells you it was added but when I look at the table it has not been added. After going through the code I am unable to see anything that jumps out at me.

Here is the form

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="add-rateing">
 <input type="text" name="MOVIE_ID">
  <input type="text" name="USER_ID">
<input type="submit" value="rate">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add-rateing").submit(function(){
event.preventDefault()

    addrateing();

   });

function addrateing()
{
var movie_id_s    = $("#add-rateing [name='MOVIE_ID']").val();
var user_id_s   = $("#add-rateing [name='USER_ID']").val();
var errors  = '';

$.ajax({
    type    : "GET",
    url     : "movie_watched.php",
    data    : { movie  : movie_id_s,
                user : user_id_s, },
    cache   : false, timeout: 10000,

    success  : function() {
        alert("added");
    },
    error    : function() {
        alert("there is a problom");
    },
    complete : function() {
    }

});
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the movie_watched.php

```
    <?php
include"scripts/connect.php" ;
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$movie = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['MOVIE_ID']);
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['USER_ID']);
$error = '';

$query=mysql_query"INSERT INTO rateing (movie_id, user_id) VALUES ('".$movie."', '".$user."')";

if (!mysql_query($query, $conn))
{
$error = mysql_error();
$return['error'] = $error;
echo json_encode($return);
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
$success = "Thank you for playing";
$return['mysql'] = $success;
echo json_encode($return);
mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: if the pop-up is coming ok, you should do a check on the values of `movie_id_s` and `user_id_s`.

Comment: it looks like these values are correct just for kicks I changed the column type to text for both of these and does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query=mysql_query"INSERT INTO rateing (movie_id, user_id) VALUES ('".$movie."', '".$user."')";
```

Should be:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO rateing (movie_id, user_id) VALUES ('".$movie."', '".$user."')");
```

Looks as if you forgot a left parenthesis.

Comment: Doing that adds an extra ( on the right, there are 2 open and close in the string.

Comment: You have a syntactical error, plain and simple. Anytime you call mysql_query, you need an opening and closing parenthesis. If you want, split up the SQL from the function like so: $sql = "INSERT INTO rateing (movie_id, user_id) VALUES ('".$movie."', '".$user."')"; $query = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: And with that we have a row added just not the correct data. That is a problem for tomorrow. Thank you I knew it had to be something simple

Comment: Glad that helps. Now that it's writing to the table, the last things you need to change is your Ajax type from GET to POST, $_POST['MOVIE_ID'] to $_POST['movie'], and $_POST['USER_ID'] to $_POST['user']. This way all of your data keys match up with your POST keys. Also, consider looking into jQuery's .post documentation for some extra information you might find useful: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Got to love those details that are easy(at least for me) to over look. Now that its working time to add it to my page. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're misunderstanding `error` and `success` in the context of a `$.ajax` call.  `success` only means that your ajax call completed successfully.  What you need to do now is check to see if you have an error.

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "GET",
    url     : "movie_watched.php",
    data    : { movie  : movie_id_s,
                user : user_id_s, },
    cache   : false, timeout: 10000,

    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(json) {
        if (json.error){
            // your php call returned successfully, but set an error code
            alert('failed : ' + json.error);
        } else {
            alert("added");
        }
    },
    error    : function() {
        alert("there is a problom");
    },
    complete : function() {
    }
});
```

Comment: I will have to look into this a little more tomorrow. Right now I cant get my brain to figure out how to add this to my code. Thank you for the tips

Comment: awesome that made things very simple for me, or my over tired brain. Thank you.